# How to run Java application by .bat file

Tags: java, batch-file

I need to run my Java Application through a .bat file.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Simply create a .bat file with the following lines in it:

```
@ECHO OFF
set CLASSPATH=.
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;path/to/needed/jars/my.jar

%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java -Xms128m -Xmx384m -Xnoclassgc ro.my.class.MyClass
```

Answer (score 14):

Sure, call the java executable.

Mine is `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe`, so to run it I would do

`C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe -jar myjarfile.jar`

Comment: That should be `java -jar myjarfile.jar` (your example is missing the `-jar`)

Answer (score 8):

If You have jar file then create bat file with:

```
java -jar NameOfJar.jar
```

Answer (score 7):

It's the same way you run it from command line. Just put that "command line" into a ".bat" file.

So, if you use `java -cp .;foo.jar Bar`, put that into a .bat file as

```
@echo off

java -cp .;foo.jar Bar
```

Answer (score 3):

```
@echo off
echo You Are going to creata Java Class
set /p Name=Enter your Class Name?:
echo Your class Name is %Name% & pause
echo To creat a Notepad
pause
notepad %Name%.java
set path=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_14\bin
pause
javac
echo Your java Path succsussfully set.
javac %Name%.java
pause
echo Successfully Compiled
java %Name%
pause
```

1)open a notpad
2)copy and past this code and save this file as 
ex: test.bat
3)Double Click tha batch file.
4)put your java codes into the notepad and save it as 
N.B.:- save this java file same folder that your batch file exists.

Comment: what's the purpose of opening up notepad when you just want to compile and run?

Answer (score 2):

`javac Application.java`

`java Application`

`pause`

The `javac` command  will compile the java program and the `java` command will run the program  and `pause` will pause the result until you cross it.

Answer (score 1):

Call the class which has main() method.

`java MyClass`

Here MyClass will have `public static void main()` method.

Answer (score 0):

- javac (.exe on Windows) binary path must be added into global PATH env. variable.

  ```
  javac MyProgram.java
  ```
- or with java (.exe on Windows).

  ```
  java MyProgram.jar
  ```

Comment: He's asking about running, not compiling