# How to run JAVA program through bat file

Tags: java, batch-file

I have already visited the Thread:[How to run java application by .bat file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938944/how-to-run-java-application-by-bat-file)
but did not help me.

I have written one java program, which uses the two external jar libraries
I am able to compile my class.So I wrote the bat file in order to execute my java class
 but I am getting Class not found exception.
My class name is Reminder.java
My bat file is

```
@ECHO ON
set CLASSPATH=.
set CLASSPATH=C:\iWaveSoftware\ITSM adapters-2.5_inst1\lib\depends\derby-10.5.3.0_1.jar,C:\iWaveSoftware\ITSM 

adapters-2.5_inst1\lib\depends\derbyclient-10.5.3.0_1.jar
JAVA -Xms100M -Xmx500M Reminder`
```

I am getting the below error if i run my windows bat file

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Reminder
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Reminder
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: Reminder.  Program will exit.
```

Thanks in Advance........Plz help me.

Comment: You're overriding the Class Path every time you do set. You want to append to it. Try: set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%,.

Comment: You should use the full class name. Eg: net.package.project.Reminder

Comment: It is stand alon java program.I am having my java file at D:/project and the same location i am having bat file

Comment: Can you please provide me sample with setting on jar path and calling the java program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) There are spaces in your classpath. Sometimes that causes error. Put classpath in quotes. ""

2) use java -cp %CLASSPATH% ... Reminder or (if it has package use package.subpackage.Reminder e.g java.util.List)

Comment: Now I wrote my bat file like below:@ECHO ON
set CLASSPATH=.
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%,C:\iWaveSoftware\ITSM adapters-2.5_inst1\lib\depends\derby-10.5.3.0_1.jar,C:\iWaveSoftware\ITSM adapters-2.5_inst1\lib\depends\derbyclient-10.5.3.0_1.jar
JAVA -Xms100M -Xmx500M Reminder

Comment: 1) Did you replace spaces? And started java using -cp?

2) Did you check what is the package for Reminder?