# Can I install created Java program on My PC?

Tags: java

I want to use My Calculator app created in java On my PC How can I use that class file to install that calculator app on my PC?

Comment: I suggest you look into using an IDE (Integrated Developing Environment), as it seems that you are compiling `.java` to `.class` by hand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a Runable-Jar-File:
[more about runable jar file](http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/createjar.html)

or create a bat-File:
[more about but file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938944/how-to-run-java-application-by-bat-file)

Comment: You have to choose a runable jar file. In eclipse go to package explorer and choose your project. In context menu take export then runable jar file.

Comment: To verify please open your `.jar` file in `winrar` and open `MANIFEST.MF` in `META-INF` folder and check for defination should like `Main-Class: com.YourClass`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert your `.jar` file into `.exe`

It will also create `installer package` of application.

Answer (score 0):

If you have builded your program correctly. You can make easy script that launch your application.
MyCalculator.bat make it as new text document and save it like this.

```
YourPathToJavaExe/java.exe "Path/to/your/java/.class/MyCalculator.class"
```

Hope it works.
Mine is this.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe
```