# Run Java program on Windows Command Line 1000 times

Tags: java, windows, loops, cmd, javac

So I have a java program... it takes two arguments and I need to run it 1000 times. The first argument doesn't change, but the second one needs go to from 1  to 1000. How do I do this? I've been trying to figure this out for a long while now :(

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read [the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Launching the JVM 1000 times is going to take much longer then writing a loop from 1 to 1000 in Java.

Comment: How come you can't use a `for` loop? Why do you need to re-execute the program 1000 times with a slightly different input each time?

Comment: I'm supposed to plot the time it takes the program to run using different buffer sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the program to take three arguments instead of two. Then use the second and third arguments to form a loop.

Originally your program maybe like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String arg1 = args[0];
    String arg2 = args[1];

    //process using arg1 and arg2
}
```

Change it to the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String arg1 = args[0];
    String arg2 = args[1];
    String arg3 = args[2];

    int loopstart = Integer.parseInt(arg2);
    int loopend = Integer.parseInt(arg3);

    for (int i = loopstart; i <= loopend; i++) {
        //process using arg1 and i <-- take note
    }
}
```

**Note:** Repeatedly calling the program from a loop in a batch file is much slower, and less desirable than actually using a loop within the program itself.

Comment: I thought it could just be done directly on the command line but I'll just do it this way... so simple haha. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a loop inside a .bat file and call the java program from it. Something like:

```
for /l %x in (1, 1, 1000) do (
 echo %x
 // call java using %x for the value of the current iteration
)
```

Calling java: [How to run java application by .bat file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938944/how-to-run-java-application-by-bat-file)